# Can HDMI output 2560x1600?

Tags: hdmi, dvi

2560x1600 is the output resoultion for dual-link dvi.  HDMI can convert to dvi.  But can HDMI convert to dual-link dvi?

I understand there are different versions of HDMI.  I want to hook up a Samsung 305T 2560x1600 monitor to a laptop with an HDMI out port.  Is this possible, and if so what are the conditions which make it possible?

Comment: How did this work out for you?  Were you able to display 2560x1600 on your DVI monitor?  I'm in the same situation and am about to give up.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HDMI revision 1.4 cable can support that resolution up to 36-bit/px (Deep Color). Provided your hardware complies with 1.4 (or 1.3 at 30bit/px), then you should be able to run that resolution. If your hardware was produced within the last few years, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

**No.** The Samsung 305T only has a dual-link DVI port.

The output must be electrically compatible with dual-link DVI to support a resolution beyond 1920x1200: A [Dual-link DVI-D connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector) or a [29-pin Type B HDMI connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Connectors) (which has not been used in any products yet).

Comment: Common [cables exist](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hdmi+to+dvi) for transposing HDMI to single link DVI and vice versa.  Does no such cable for HDMI 1.4 to dual link DVI?  Is such a cable impossible, impractical, or is such a cable not yet on the market?

Comment: HDMI 1.4 uses higher clocks, while Dual link DVI uses more lanes. So a simple passive adapter cable is not possible, it would require active conversions.

Answer (score 1):

There are so-called ACTIVE adaptors which can convert HDMI to dual-link DVI. They cost around 100 dollars or so.
The real question, however, is whether your notebook can output a resolution above 1080p via HDMI - most can't. The Geforce 330m and 540m for example don't support it.

Comment: The notebook is not yet purchased - still in planning phase.  Assuming the notebook's video can output 2560x1600, I would just need to purchase an active adapter?  Does "active" mean the adapter must do processing, and does this slow the transfer rate appreciably?

Comment: @JM. if you haven't purchased the notebook yet, why not just look for one that supports DisplayPort? You can get a DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter for about $25, and won't be limited by HDMI's problems with going above 1920x1200.

Comment: Where did you see such an adapter?